# How to ad ops to a tensorflow graph created from frozen model serving graph?

Tags: tensorflow

I am loading a tensorflow graph that has been serialized for model serving. I'm trying to use it in some code that goes back to the training data. That code creates tensorflow ops to iterate through the tfrecords training data - but for some reason, once I create a session with the serving graph, I can't using dataset iterator from training? This is what is happening:

Code to write out the graph:

```py
output_graph_def = \
        tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess=sess,
            input_graph_def=tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(),
            output_node_names=['predict'])

 with tf.gfile.GFile('graph.pb', "wb") as f:
        f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Loading the graph:

```py
def load_graph_pb(frozen_graph_filename):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    # import graph_def into default Graph
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(
            graph_def,
            input_map=None,
            return_elements=None,
            op_dict=None,
            producer_op_list=None
        )
    return graph

tf.reset_default_graph()
graph = load_graph_pb('graph.pb')
```

Create a session with that graph:

```py
 sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
```

Then create a dataset iterator:

```py
def batchIter(sess, datafile):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(datafile) \
              ...
    tf_iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    get_next = tf_iter.get_next()
    sess.run(tf_iter.initializer)
    while True:
        batch = sess.run(get_next)
        yield batch
```

But when I try to use it,

```py
iter = batchIter(sess, 'train.tfrec')
batch = next(iter)
```

I get

```py
ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Operation 'MakeIterator' type=MakeIterator> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Operation name: "MakeIterator"
op: "MakeIterator"
input: "ParallelMapDataset"
input: "Iterator"
attr {
  key: "_class"
  value {
    list {
      s: "loc:@Iterator"
    }
  }
}
 is not an element of this graph.)
```

I guess I called `sess(graph=graph)` to early? I must have to make the iter ops before doing that, but I also have to make sure they go into this `graph` I loaded? I think I know what the problem is, elegant solutions welcome :)

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find the solution for this?

Comment: sorry, I can't remember